# Inrush current limiter thermistor acting up

Tags: audio, thermistor, power-amplifier, inrush-current, shock

One of the power amps I am working on uses a thermistor for inrush current limiting (SL15 25003) as shown in the schematic below (ICL1). When I was testing the unit it seemed to me that there was some excessive heat coming from around that area, but only when the unit was running in a horizontal position (weird). When I touched the thermistor (after powering off) I got shocked pretty good. At first I thought I accidentally touched one of the large capacitors next to it, so I tried again and got shocked again. Is this normal?

[image]

Comment: Please explain *exactly* how you are removing power. Where is the power switch? Or are you unplugging something? The thermistor can't hold a charge. T1 won't let C72 hold a charge. Probably C71.

Comment: There is a power switch where J25 is. I just checked the wall plug and the unit was powered the other way around than the drawing, so J25 was neutral with switch and J24 was hot. First time, I was touching the grounded case with my right hand and the thermistor with my left. The shock went all the way through my left hand - chest - right hand. Second time, I only touched the thermistor with my left hand, the shock went up my forearm, stopped around the elbow. Nothing looks wrong with the thermistor insulation.

Comment: Any *coating* on a component is designed to protect the component, not you. If J24 was *hot* because your plug was reversed, then most of the components shown will be *hot*.